# Nested JSON file

Tags: javascript, json

I have this JSON file with a bunch of records. This is just a part of it:

```
   {
    "data_id": 12,
    "title": "Lorem",
    "description": "Lorem.",
    "subdata": [{
        "sd_id": 1,
        "title": "Lorem",
        "question_type": "mutiplechoice-single",
        "subsubdata": [{
            "sdd_id": 1,
            "text": "Joe"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 2,
            "text": "Steph"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 3,
            "text": "George"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 4,
            "text": "Jake"
        }],
        "num": 1,
        "counter": 2
    }, {
        "sd_id": 1,
        "title": "Lorem",
        "question_type": "mutiplechoice-single",
        "subsubdata": [{
            "sdd_id": 1,
            "text": "Joe"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 2,
            "text": "Steph"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 3,
            "text": "George"
        }, {
            "sdd_id": 4,
            "text": "Jake"
        }],
        "num": 1,
        "counter": 2
    }]
}
```

and this is my JavaScript code:

```
var data;
function preload() {
    data = loadJSON("file.json");
}

function setup() {
    noCanvas();
  var value = data.subdata[1].subsubdata[1].text;
  createP(question);
}
```

I've tried to read examples on the internet but most of them are using simple JSON files. The JSON im using is a bit more complex and I cant figure out how to get the values inside of another.

This is my first time using JavaScript and JSON to be blunt. Can you guys give some hints how to proceed?

Comment: Nothing obviously wrong with that. What's the problem? What does your console report in the way of errors?

Comment: you could use `JSON.parse`, if not already done.

Comment: What is your question dude?

Comment: @DavidFischer The code I wrote is not working and I cant figure out why.

Comment: Are you running `preload()` first then `setup()`? Otherwise your data is `undefined`

Comment: @Bobys — "not working" isn't a clear problem statement and the code you have supplied isn't a [mcve]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One example how to get some information out of a deeper JSON hierarchy:

```
var jsonString = var jsonString = '{ "data_id": 12, "title": "Lorem", "description": "Lorem.", "subdata": [{ "sd_id": 1, "title": "Lorem", "question_type": "mutiplechoice-single", "subsubdata": [{ "sdd_id": 1, "text": "Joe" }, { "sdd_id": 2, "text": "Steph" }, { "sdd_id": 3, "text": "George" }, { "sdd_id": 4, "text": "Jake" }], "num": 1, "counter": 2 }, { "sd_id": 1, "title": "Lorem", "question_type": "mutiplechoice-single", "subsubdata": [{ "sdd_id": 1, "text": "Joe" }, { "sdd_id": 2, "text": "Steph" }, { "sdd_id": 3, "text": "George" }, { "sdd_id": 4, "text": "Jake" }], "num": 1, "counter": 2 }] }';
var jsonObject = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var someString = jsonObject.subdata[0].subsubdata[1].text;
```

As you can see, you can easily parse a JSON string into an actual Object. Then you can just move up and down the hierarchy as you please.